# unexpected copies with foreach over a map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, foreach, auto

I am trying to loop over the entries of a map, and I get unexpected copies. Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct X
{
    X()
    {
        std::cout << "default constructor\n";
    }

    X(const X&)
    {
        std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, X> numbers = {{1, X()}, {2, X()}, {3, X()}};
    std::cout << "STARTING LOOP\n";
    for (const std::pair<int, X>& p : numbers)
    {
    }
    std::cout << "ENDING LOOP\n";
}
```

And here is the output:

```
default constructor
copy constructor
default constructor
copy constructor
default constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
STARTING LOOP
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
ENDING LOOP
```

Why do I get three copies inside the loop? The copies disappear if I use type inference:

```
for (auto&& p : numbers)
{
}
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The value type of `map<K,V>` is `pair<const K,V>`; so your loop needs to convert `pair<const int,X>` to `pair<int,X>`, copying both the key and the value, to give you a reference to that type.

Using the correct type (specified explicitly, or deduced with `auto`) will remove the copies.

Comment: In theory, couldn't the language allow to bind a `const pair<K, V>&` to a `pair<const K, V>`? Or would that leave a hole in the const-correctness system? Could I break anything if it were allowed?

Comment: @FredOverflow: it would change the methods called (between `const` qualified and not), that makes me queasy.

Comment: @FredOverflow: There is also the problem of the properties of the types used to instantiate a template not being propagated to the intantiated template. `std::pair<X,Y>` is unrelated to `std::pair<T,U>` unless `X` is exactly `T` and `Y` is exactly `U`. Support for that binding you request cannot be done at the language level, as it depends on the implementation of the template, there might be a specialization of the template for types that are `const` in which case the real type and footprint of `T<U>` might be completely different than that of `T<const U>`

Answer (score 5):

The `value_type` in a `std::map<K, V>` is **not** `std::pair<K, V>` but rather `std::pair<K const, V>`. That is, you can't change the key component of the elements. If the compiler finds a request to get a `std::pair<K, V> const&` from a `std::pair<K const, K> const&` it uses the conversion constructor of `std::pair<...>` and creates a suitable temporary.

I'd recommend using `value_type` instead to avoid any differences:

```
for (std::map<int, X>::value_type const& p: numbers)
    ...
```

Alternatively you can have the type be deduced:

```
for (auto const& p: number)
    ...
```

Comment: In theory, couldn't the language allow to bind a `const pair<K, V>&` to a `pair<const K, V>`? Or would that leave a hole in the const-correctness system? Could I break anything if it were allowed?

Comment: `const pair<K, V>&` to `pair<const K, V>` breaks V. `pair<const K, V>` to `const pair<K, V>&` might break K (if K is later marked mutable).

Comment: @FredOverflow: The compiler has no knowledge of how the template arguments are being used. The instantiations with different types are considered entirely different type.

Comment: If there were any approach to address the problem, it would be to prohibit the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 4):

The copies are due to the fact that you are iterating a map but binding the wrong reference type. The `value_type` for that map is `std::pair<const int, X>` (note the `const`). Because they are not the same type, the compiler is creating a temporary and binding the reference.

You can (probably should) iterator using `auto&` or `const auto&` in most cases, which will avoid this kind of issues. If you want spell out the type, you can use the nested `value_type` or the exact type:

```
for (const std::map<int,X>::value_type& r : numbers) {
// or
for (const std::pair<const int,X>& r : numbers) {
```

The preference should be: `const auto& r` then `const std::map<...>::value_type&` and then `const std::pair<const int, X>&`. Note that the further to the right in the list, the more *knowledge* you are providing and the less you allow the compiler to help you.

Comment: In theory, couldn't the language allow to bind a `const pair<K, V>&` to a `pair<const K, V>`? Or would that leave a hole in the const-correctness system? Could I break anything if it were allowed?

Comment: Nasty implicit conversion of a std::pair +1.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Already answered in the comment you made above. Simple answer: No, that cannot be done at the language level.