# why does std::for_each iterator need a copy constructable iterator

Tags: c++11, stl, iterator

I noticed that std::for_each requires it's iterators to meet the requirement InputIterator, which in turn requires Iterator and then Copy{Contructable,Assignable}.

That's not the only thing, std::for_each actually uses the copy constructor (cc) (not assignment as far as my configuration goes). That is, deleting the cc from the iterator will result in:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘some_iterator::some_iterator(const some_iterator&)’
```

Why does std::for_each need a cc? I found this particularly inconvenient, since I created an iterator which recursively iterates through files in a folder, keeping track of the files and folders on a queue. This means that the iterator has a queue data member, which would also have to be copied if the cc is used: that is unnecessarily inefficient.

The strange thing is that the cc is not called in this simple example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


class infinite_5_iterator
:
public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int>
{
public:
  infinite_5_iterator() = default;
  infinite_5_iterator(infinite_5_iterator const &) {std::cout << "copy constr "; }

  infinite_5_iterator &operator=(infinite_5_iterator const &) = delete;


  int operator*() { return 5; }
  infinite_5_iterator &operator++() { return *this; }
  bool operator==(infinite_5_iterator const &) const { return false; }
  bool operator!=(infinite_5_iterator const &) const { return true; }
};

int main() {
  std::for_each(infinite_5_iterator(), infinite_5_iterator(),
    [](int v) {
      std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
  );
}
```

source: http://ideone.com/YVHph8

It however is needed compile time. Why does std::for_each need to copy construct the iterator, and when is this done? Isn't this extremely inefficient?

NOTE: I'm talking about the cc of the iterator, not of it's elements, as is done here: [unexpected copies with foreach over a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709342/unexpected-copies-with-foreach-over-a-map)

EDIT: Note that the standard does not state the copy-constructor is called at all, it just expresses the amount of times f is called. May I then assume that the cc is not called at all? Why is the use of operator++ and operator* and cc not specified, but the use of f is?

[image: std::for_each documentation]

Comment: "Not called". The compiler is allowed to optimize away copying. however, this does not change the fact that a copy ctor must be available in certain situations.

Comment: Yes, it is required but not necessarily called. My question is, WHEN would/may it be called. This is important for the efficiency of for_each, is it called each iterator? Only once at the beginning? Is it never called? Moreover, why is it really *needed*. I don't see why when std::for_each can just use a reference and a prefix++. I can write a for-loop which iterates of an iterator, but does not require a cc or ca. Does that mean that for-loops are more efficient that std::for_each?

Comment: std::for_each receives its arguments by value. This alone requires an accessible cc, regardless of what additional requirements are imposed on them.

Comment: I also get that, and I'm happy to see my compiler applies copy elision there. Nevertheless, might std::for_each copy the iterator more often or even each iteration? Consider an iterator with a vector inside, keeping an index of the location. If that iterator is copied each iteration, iterating over the elements takes O(n*n) instead of O(n): hence it matters to know about the efficiency of std::for_each.

Comment: The standard says nothing about that, it's for the implementation to decide. If your iteratirs are heavy to copy you may have a performance degradation. Iterators are not supposed to be heavy. You may consider another internal bookkeeping data structure with O(1) copying (a singly-linked-list-based stack with shared nodes for example).

Comment: Note that the standard requires Iterators in general to be CopyConstructable (for the purposes of the standard library anyway). See C++11 24.2.2/2 "Iterator".  In general Iterators are supposed to refer to items in a container or stream, not contain the items being iterated over. You might want to consider refactoring your file system iterator to refer to a single instance of the queue data structure instead of containing it. `shared_ptr<>` might help with that.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you :) I hear you loud and clear. But if I'm not mistaken the general idea of an InputIterator is that you can iterator through it **once**, otherwise you have a ForwardIterator. So I don't really see why it can't be passed by reference everwhere. Wouldn't it make sense to have a std::for_each which only accepts an rvalue reference and needs no cc? This way it is clear that for_each *takes ownership* of the iterator.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Yes, thank you. I know about these facilities and I can do a PIMPL. However, IMHO it's ludacris that one needs to develop something which should not be needed. I really don't see why std::for_each needs to copy an InputIterator, when it (1) iterates through it and (2) the iterator by definition becomes invalid after one iteration. Why does it make sense to pass by value, when the iterator in the scope of where std::for_each is called becomes invalid anyway.

Comment: @MichaelBurr if you "point" to a file in a folder hierarchy, you normally use its full pathname, which is O(n) to copy in the worst case. It is possible to build an in-memory representation of the folder hierarchy, and point to its internal nodes instead. That would entail cheaper copying, but require more code.

Comment: @Herbert It's perfectly valid and sensible to call `for_each` with something stronger than input iterators, in which case the caller's iterators would not become invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have simply fallen victim to a specification that has evolved in bits and pieces over decades.  The concept of `InputIterator` was invented a long time before the notion of move-only types, or movable types was conceived.

In hindsight I would love to declare that `InputIterator` need not be copyable.  This would mesh perfectly with its single-pass behavior.  But I also fear that such a change would have overwhelming backwards compatibility problems.

In addition to the flawed iterator concepts as specified in the standard, about a decade ago, in an attempt to be helpful, the gcc std::lib (libstdc++) started imposing "concepts" on things like `InputIterator` in the std-algorithms.  I.e. because the standard says:

> *Requires:* `InputIterator` shall satisfy the requirements of an input iterator (24.2.3).

then "concept checks" were inserted into the std-algorithms that require `InputIterator` to meet all of the requirements of input iterator *whether or not the algorithm actually used all of those requirements.*  And in this case, it is the concept check, not the actual algorithm, that is requiring your iterator to be `CopyConstructible`.

<sigh>

If you write your own `for_each` algorithm, it is trivial to do so without requiring your iterators to be `CopyConstructible` or `CopyAssignable` (if supplied with rvalue iterator arguments):

```
template <class InputIterator, class Function>
inline
Function
for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        f(*first);
    return f;
}
```

And for your use case I recommend either doing that, or simply writing your own loop.

Comment: Are the codes you provided being "your own" or being standard? I found it the same as here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/?kw=for_each

Comment: @MarsonMao:  The standard doesn't specify the implementation of `for_each`.  I've implemented this function for two commercial std::lib products, and this is how I've implemented it both times, modulo putting underscores everywhere.  There's just not much to it.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thank you. Maybe it might be a good idea for std::for_each to specify (in the standard) how often the cc is called (at most) under "complexity" ? This way there is no need for building light weight single-pass iterators.

Comment: @HowardHinnant And why these "concept checks" cannot be removed or loosed now to allow user-defined non-copyable iterators in `std::for_each`? AFAIU this cannot break the backward compatibility since it only widens the applicability of STL algorithms.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0:  I'm not sure if you're referring to an implementation, or the standard specification.  If you are referring to an implementation, then file a bug against the implementation to do so.  libc++ (for example) already does not have this burdensome concept check: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm#L867-L875 .  If you are talking about getting the standard changed, that is much harder.  You would need to get involved on the committee (the door is open, https://isocpp.org).