# Why do iterators need to be CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable?

Tags: c++, iterator

According to [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) and VC++ 14.0, iterators need to have copy constructors and copy assignment operators.

My iterator class(it iterates through Windows processes) can't ever be copy-constructible or copy-assignable - it holds a `HANDLE` to snapshot and manages freeing it so it's impossible to copy those - moving them is possible, I supplied a move constructor and move assignment operator. However, algorithm `std::find_if` copies them(in VC++ 14.0 is calls some `std::_Find_if` which requires copying the iterator) and doesn't want to work.

> Why does your iterator hold on to a resource? An iterator should be like a pointer where it points to something.

Because in order to iterate through Windows processes, you need to create a snapshot, and then use it to do so - the problem is, one snapshot, one iteration. Also snapshot isn't copyable.

**Why can't they just be `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable`? Which algorithms(if any) truly need copying iterators to work?**

Comment: Why does your iterator hold on to a resource?  An iterator should be like a pointer where it points to something.

Comment: @NathanOliver, this is not true. stream iterators, for instance, are nothing like pointers.

Comment: Counting iterators, and anything that generates a value, can hold such state internally. In general InputIterators are allowed to store things inside them (sometimes called "stashing iterators"), but that's not possible for anything that meets the ForwardIterator requirements.

Comment: @SergeyA Stream iterators are a different beast the regular iterators.

Comment: @NathanOliver, they are still valid, standard-conformin iterators. So your statement is generally wrong.

Comment: Yes, they are just InputIterators or OutputIterators, the most degenerate form of iterator with the weakest requirements.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I am not sure if you can call them degenerate. They are pretty OK to be used in most of the algorithms.

Comment: Because in order to iterate through Windows processes, you need to create a snapshot(which can't be copied) first and you can't use a snapshot to more than one iteration.

Comment: @Fireho, that doesn't prevent you from storing the state outside an iterator, and having the iterators refer to it e.g. via `shared_ptr`. InputIterators are single pass (i.e. only support a single iteration) but are still copyable.

Comment: But when I'd copy such an iterator and modify the copy, the original would also be modified.

Comment: @Fireho...and that's the defining characteristic of input-only iterators :) They are single-pass, and incrementing one invalidates all copies of the previous value.

Comment: @Fireho: imo you should just make a separate "WindowState" or "WindowIteratorContext" object which holds the snapshot, and then it can have `begin()` `end()` methods which yield iterators which are simple pointers. You're trying to make one class do too many things imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Due to historical reasons.

I think, it's more or less obvious why `ForwardIterator` and other more functional iterators need to be copyable. As for `InputIterator` and `OutputIterator`, the situation is a bit more complicated.

The `InputIterator` and `OutputIterator` have one-pass nature which coincides perfectly well with the move-only class concept. Now, when you use any of these iterators from the standard library (let's say it's `istream_iterator` for example), you may copy it and dereference the copy, but advancement of any of the copies would advance all of them, which does not look like an expected behavior.

Unfortunately, at the moment of writing many of the STL algorithms (like `std::find_if`, `std::copy`, etc) there were no move semantics at all, and there was no way of requiring the `InputIterator` to be move-constructible.

Since then, on some platforms STL algorithms actually require the iterator given to be copyable (like in this case), and on other platforms (like g++ AFAIK) this behavior is required by the concept of `InputIterator` which is checked in compile time each time you use STL algorithms.

Also, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27767611/1989995) useful.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators should not hold resources; they are abstractions of pointers, and should be cheap to copy. The entire standard library assumes this.

Use a separate (move-only) class to manage the `HANDLE`; your iterators should store a pointer to that class.

Comment: Iterators are NOT neccessarily absatraction of pointers, look at stream iterators.

Comment: @SergeyA [iterator.requirements.general]/p1: "Iterators are a generalization of pointers that allow a C++ program to work with different data structures
(containers) in a uniform manner."

Comment: This statement is obviously incorrect. Like I said, stream iterators are not pointers.

Comment: @SergeyA, maybe you should tell that to Stepanov then. Stream iterators "point" to a stream, they just happen to store some state (such as the last character read) internally.

Comment: @JonathanWakely They store much more than the last character. They store the reference to the stream.

Comment: Well yes, of course they do. Like I said, they "point" to the stream. But that's not "state" it's a pointer/reference to external state (hey, that's a bit like a pointer!) Are you here just to argue with everything everyone says?

Answer (score -1):

Well, how can they be not?
Simplest possible find would look something like it:

```
for (IT i = begin_iterator, e = end_iterator; i != e; ++i)
```

And how would it construct i?

Comment: As [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) demonstrates, it's perfectly possible to write a `find_if` that doesn't copy the iterator.

Comment: `for (IT i = std::move(begin_iterator), e = std::move(end_iterator); i != e; ++i)`. However, you don't even need to create `i` and `e` - you can just do `for (;begin_iterator != end_iterator; ++begin_iterator)`.

Comment: This version copies the iterators as a way of getting it's arguments. I was referring to the theoretical implementation which would accept values by const reference (as the version which accepts them by value obviously copies)

Comment: @Fireho, see above. By accepting those iterators as an argument, you would invariably copy them.

Comment: No, because you can move them when you call the function. That's why you can pass `unique_ptr` by value.

Comment: Unique_ptr does not have copy constructor by design. Regular iterators do. I am not sure what is the point you are trying to make.

Comment: The point is that it is perfectly possible to write a `find_if` that works with a move-only "iterator" type.

Comment: I never said it is impossible, I just provided the example. Standard does not burden the implementation developers with a requirement to make their implementations move-only whenever possible.