# std::for_each no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::pair<const point, int>' to 'std::pair<point, int>&'

Tags: c++, std

I cannot understand, as the both cases look so similar, in first for_each i cannot get reference to pair, and in second I get the reference to pair with no fuss. Could anybody please explain it to me?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct table_info_t {
    char name[32] = {0};
    int posx;
    int posy;

    table_info_t(const char *name, int posx, int posy) : posx(posx), posy(posy) {
        strncpy(this->name, name, 31);
    }
};

struct point {
    int posx;
    int posy;

    point(int posx, int posy) : posx(posx), posy(posy) { }
};

size_t hashstruct(const char* hptr, size_t size) {
    size_t h = 31;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        h = (h + *hptr) * 31;
        hptr++;
    }
    return h;
}

#define MAP_OPERATORS(typ)\
namespace std {\
\
    template<>\
    struct hash<typ> {\
        std::size_t operator()(const typ &k) const { return hashstruct((const char*)&k, sizeof(typ)); }\
    };\
\
    bool operator==(const typ& one, const typ& other) { return memcmp(&one, &other, sizeof(typ)) == 0; }\
};

MAP_OPERATORS(point); //hash structure and operator==
MAP_OPERATORS(table_info_t); //hash structure and operator==

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::unordered_map<point, int> sp;
    sp[point(3, 4)] = 7;
    std::for_each(sp.begin(), sp.end(),
                  [](std::pair<point, int> pair) {
                      std::cout << pair.first.posx << "+" <<pair.first.posy << "=" << pair.second << "\n";
                  });

    std::unordered_map<table_info_t, const char *> m;
    m[table_info_t("make my day", 3, 14)] = "make my day 3,14";

    std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(),
                  [](std::pair<const table_info_t, const char * >& pair)
                  {
                      std::cout << pair.first.name << pair.first.posx << pair.first.posy << " " << pair.second << "\n";
                  }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Both structures do not differ so much, but when compiling this, I get this error:

```
In file included from .../4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/algorithm:62:0,
                 from .../src/main/c/hashtable.cpp:10:
.../4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const point, int>, false, true>; _Funct = main(int, char**)::__lambda0]':
.../src/main/c/hashtable.cpp:45:24:   required from here
.../4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:4417:14: error: no match for call to '(main(int, char**)::__lambda0) (std::pair<const point, int>&)'
  __f(*__first);
              ^
.../src/main/c/hashtable.cpp:43:24: note: candidates are:
                       [](std::pair<point, int> &pair) {
                        ^
In file included from .../4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/algorithm:62:0,
                 from .../src/main/c/hashtable.cpp:10:
.../4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:4417:14: note: void (*)(std::pair<point, int>&) <conversion>
  __f(*__first);
              ^
.../4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:4417:14: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 2 provided
.../src/main/c/hashtable.cpp:43:53: note: main(int, char**)::__lambda0
                       [](std::pair<point, int> &pair) {
                                                     ^
.../src/main/c/hashtable.cpp:43:53: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::pair<const point, int>' to 'std::pair<point, int>&'
```

and I need to remove the reference. However reference to pair<const table_info_t, const char * > is perfectly fine for the compiler in second for_each.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `const table_info_t` is correct, key types have const, the error is from the first `for_each`

Comment: Thanks @PasserBy I fixed the error description with missing lt and gt tags, so it's more clear now what the error is.

Comment: @user_pj Don't post code in comments! Edit your questions to make sure that your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) really is complete and verifiable. And when editing the question, please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output of the compiler and/or linker into the question body as well. And then mark out the line(s) where the errors are in your code, with e.g. a comment.

Comment: thank you @Someprogrammerdude - fixed this.

Comment: If you have access to c++14, `[](const auto& pair)`, so you cannot forget the const KEY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you iterate over `std::unordered_map<Key, Value>`,
you iterate on `std::pair<const KEY, VALUE>`

In the second case, you take `std::pair<const KEY, VALUE>&` so it is fine.
You might even add const as you don't change the pair: `const std::pair<const KEY, VALUE>&`.

In the first case, you use another type `std::pair<KEY, VALUE>&`.
`std::pair<KEY, VALUE>` can be constructed from `std::pair<const KEY, VALUE>`. However, a temporary can not be bound to non-const lvalue-reference. So using `std::pair<KEY, VALUE>&` is invalid. Using `std::pair<KEY, VALUE>` is valid but does extra copies. See [unexpected copies with foreach over a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709342/unexpected-copies-with-foreach-over-a-map) for details.

If you have access to C++14, you may simplify it using a generic lambda:

```
[](const auto& p) {
    std::cout << p.first.posx << "+" << p.first.posy << "=" << p.second << "\n";
});
```

In addition `std::for_each` can also be replaced by a range-based for loop (even in C++11):

```
for(const auto& p : sp) {
    std::cout << p.first.posx << "+" << p.first.posy << "=" << p.second << "\n";
};
```

Comment: While not relevant in this case, `std::for_each` would allow for trivial parallel execution in later (vanilla) C++, unlike a range for.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: transforming `for range` to `for_each` is not difficult either in that case...